# Returning binary value from select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary, binary-search

I have created the following simple query:

```
substring(SELECT DB_NAME(), 1, 1)
```

I want to receive the result as a binary string (like 11001011).

Meaning, to recieve the selected "char" as binary.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `SELECT CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARBINARY(MAX))`

Comment: Binary value(only with 1's and 0's) can't be extracted from SQLServer. VARBINARY will give you hexadecimal binary value but it will have characters. Is there any specific reason you want the output in 1's and 0's?

Comment: Yes, there is. is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Sorry you can't do that in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast string, you can try next SQL query

```
SELECT CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARBINARY(MAX)) as db_binary_name
```

I've written small T-SQL function to convert varchar value to string binary value. Hope, this will be useful.

```
CREATE FUNCTION StrToBin
(
    @str VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @binary_value VARBINARY(MAX),
            @output_str NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @temp_str NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @part_binary_value VARBINARY(1),
            @start_pos BIGINT

    SET @binary_value = CAST(@str AS VARBINARY(MAX))
    SET @start_pos = 1

    WHILE @start_pos <= LEN(@binary_value)
    BEGIN
        SET @temp_str = NULL
        SET @part_binary_value = NULL

        SET @part_binary_value = SUBSTRING(@binary_value, @start_pos, 1)

        WHILE @part_binary_value NOT IN(0,1)
        BEGIN 
            SET @temp_str = ISNULL(@temp_str, '') + CAST(@part_binary_value % 2 AS VARCHAR(1))
            SET @part_binary_value = @part_binary_value / 2

            IF @part_binary_value = 1
                SET @temp_str = @temp_str + '1' 
        END

        IF @temp_str IS NULL
            SET @temp_str = '0'
        ELSE
            SET @temp_str = REVERSE(@temp_str)

        -- padding 
        IF LEN(@temp_str) < 8
            SET @temp_str = REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(@temp_str)) + @temp_str

        SET @output_str = ISNULL(@output_str, '') + @temp_str
        SET @start_pos = @start_pos + 1
    END

    RETURN @output_str
END
GO
```

For example

```
SELECT dbo.StrToBin(DB_Name()) as col_name
```

Comment: will this return the db_name as a string of 1 and 0's ?

Comment: No, as binary data. Do you want get string with 1 and 0 values?

Comment: yes. I'm willing to recieve a string as "1101101010111100101.."

Comment: @pwnphpown, you can convert the binary value to a hex string with `CONVERT` and a style 1 specification:  `CONVERT(varchar(256), CAST(DB_NAME() AS varbinary(256)), 1)`

Comment: @Dan what will be the full query with the select? or should I use 2 queries in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast or convert

```
SELECT CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARBINARY)
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY,DB_NAME())
```

Comment: will this return the db_name as a string of 1 and 0's?

Comment: No it will convert it to sql varbinary